# Move JS arrays rows in a new JS filtered array by field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have JS array in json format such as this one:

[image]

Once the user will see all the rows, there is an option to filter specific fields only in specific order. I'm able to filter the fields but I'm trying now to have them reordered in specific order too.

For example, user has selected these three fields in that specific order, please check the list on the right:

[image]

I want to filter out only those three columns in that specific order:

opentime

openingmode

extdoorid

What are my options now, how can I push only these specific rows in a new array which I'll use as filtered array later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [run through your array](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) and, inside of it, check if the attribute name is inside of your field list. You add what you need in one object, then push it to your list.

```js
var arr = [
  { opentime: 'opentime1', openingmode: 'openingmode1', extdoorid: 'extdoorid1', automaticchangestableid: 'acsid1', extdoorid: 'edid1'},
  {opentime: 'opentime2', openingmode: 'openingmode2', extdoorid: 'extdoorid2', automaticchangestableid: 'acsid2', extdoorid: 'edid2'},
  {opentime: 'opentime3', openingmode: 'openingmode3', extdoorid: 'extdoorid3', automaticchangestableid: 'acsid3', extdoorid: 'edid3'}
  ];
var fieldList = [ 'automaticchangestableid',  'opentime', 'extdoorid'];
var newArr = [];

angular.forEach(arr, function(value, index) {
  var obj = {};
  angular.forEach(fieldList, function(field, fieldIndex){
      obj[field] = value[field];
  });
  newArr.push(obj);
});

console.log(newArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I need but do you think we can reshuffle the things little bit, because for example if the openingmode is set as first item in the table and opentime second, the array still shows them in the original order https://i.gyazo.com/7c4f69900a42019569417b1d7fdd25c5.png what do you think? Thx

Comment: Sorry, fixed now. :)

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. Do you know why at the end of the inner loop the array sorts alphabetically by default?

Comment: Sorts alphabetically? It will sort the way you insert. If you insert `openingmode` first, then `extdoorid`, it will be `{openingmode: x, extdoorid: y}`

Comment: For some odd reason it changes the array to alphabetical sort before pushing them to the real array https://i.gyazo.com/bf1feaaee22a86f2387ae193b4477733.png although during the foreach loop it loops fine

Comment: You're not filtering your `fieldList` alphabetically?

Comment: Nope https://i.gyazo.com/73d4512d567f9e8efa695f2ed1cde7bd.png thanks again for your help, I appreciate a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161537/discussion-between-m-jr-and-laziale).

Comment: Can you post some code to show me what you're doing to fill the `keys` array? I've updated the code in the way you're working, you can see that it works here. :P

Comment: What is the usage of this var keys = Object.keys(fieldList); and also the list can be dynamic, I can see you hard code the three fields in the fieldList, do you think that can make a difference? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, after applying this line $scope.sortedAssets.sort(); everything works just fine.